# Ambiguity in Num typeclass

Tags: haskell

I cannot figure out why following code directly executed in ghci works

```
Prelude> import Data.Aeson
Prelude Data.Aeson> toJSON 3
Number 3.0
```

And this this simple program

```
import Data.Aeson
main = print . toJSON $ 3
```

fails with error

```
/mnt/data/Maggot/tmp.hs:2:16:
    No instance for (ToJSON s0) arising from a use of ‘toJSON’
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘toJSON’
    In the expression: print . toJSON
    In the expression: print . toJSON $ 3
/mnt/data/Maggot/tmp.hs:2:25:
    No instance for (Num s0) arising from the literal ‘3’
    The type variable ‘s0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      ...plus 17 others
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘3’
    In the expression: print . toJSON $ 3
    In an equation for ‘main’: main = print . toJSON $ 3
```

I know I could directly specify type (3 :: Int), but I am curios how to work this around?
Thanks.

Comment: GHCi has different default-type rules than the compiler. The idea being that when you're trying stuff out in GHCi, you don't want to be pestered by this stuff, but when compiling the final program you want to be explicit about what you want.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid care to make your comment into an answer?

Comment: @bheklilr I could do... Do you think it answers the entire question?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid OP does ask for a work around for this problem, I guess you could mention `ExtendedDefaultRules`, but the message should still be "Add type signatures, it's the best practices" IMO.

Comment: Thanks! One more question, why `default (Int)` does not solve the issue? I thought its purpose, is exactly to resolve type ambiguities in `Num` type class?

Comment: I guess, I know the answer. `The type variable a appears in no other constraints`?